# C# simple reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a class that contains another poco class with simple get set properties:

```
public class PersonalInformation    {
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string FirstSomethingElse { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to find out if the current instance's PersonalInformation.FirstName has a value. I can't figure out how to obtain it via reflection:

```
foreach (PropertyInfo property in this.PersonalInformation.GetType().GetProperties())
{
    if (property.Name.Contains("First"))
    {
    if (property.GetValue(XXX, null) != null)
                            do something...

    }
}
```

The instance I have is "this", which does not work, neither does this.PersonalInformation. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you for your response,

Aldo

Addendum: I'm using ASP.NET MVC3. In my razor view I can do the following very easily:

```
foreach (var property in Model.PersonalInformation.GetType().GetProperties()) 
{
    <div class="editor-line">
        @if (property.Name != null)
        {
        <label>@(property.Name)</label>
        @Html.Editor(property.Name)
        }
    </div>
}
```

there is a property.Value member that returns the current value of the field. This field comes from a poco class, as you see above. What would be the equivalent code in the code-behind?

Comment: what do you mean by "doesn't work"

Comment: Why are you using reflection?

Comment: What have you tried? Do you get an exception? Should you be using reflection?

Comment: >> What do you mean by "doesn't work?" - means I'm getting an object exception

Comment: >> Why are you using reflection? : this is an ultrasimplified example. Let's pretend I have hundreds of properties in my form.

Comment: >> What have you tried? - I'll post full source. I don't want to iterate through every single poco property but I don't know if reflection is the correct approach. I'll clarify.

Comment: When you say "has a value" do you mean "is not null"?  OR should you use `(value != null && value.ToString().Length != 0)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`this.PersonalInformation` certainly *should* work. After all, that's the target you're talking about.

Sample code:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;

public class PersonalInformation    {
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string FirstSomethingElse { get; set; }
}

public class Foo 
{
    public PersonalInformation PersonalInformation { get; set; }

    public void ShowProperties()
    {
        foreach (var property in this.PersonalInformation
                                     .GetType()
                                     .GetProperties())
        {
            var value = property.GetValue(this.PersonalInformation, null);
            Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", property.Name, value);
        }
    }
}

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Foo foo = new Foo { 
            PersonalInformation = new PersonalInformation {
                FirstName = "Fred",
                FirstSomethingElse = "XYZ"
            }
        };
        foo.ShowProperties();
    }
}
```

Although if you just "want to find out if the current instance's PersonalInformation.FirstName has a value" then I don't see why you're using reflection...

Answer (score -3):

GetProperties returns a PropertyInfo[], not a single PropertyInfo.

Comment: ... which is why he's iterating over them.